# firestore rule to validate multiple create in batch

Tags: validation, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am writing an application where users can place comments in threads. Since I am using Firestore's NoSQL backend for this, I store each comment in two places:

```
/threads/THREADID/comments/COMMENTID
/users/USERID/comments/COMMENTID
```

This way, I have an overview of all the comments in a thread, but also of all the comments a user has posted. To make sure that these two comments are always both created, I use a batch write. Batch writes are atomic so this should never cause any problems, but my concern is that a malicious user could use custom code to create a comment in only one location and not in both. I need to find a rule that validates that either both comments is created, or neither of them is should.

```
  match /users/{userId}/comments/{commentId} {  
    allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/threads/$(request.resource.data.threadId)/comments/$(commentId)
  }

  match /threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId} {  
    allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/comments/$(commentId)
  }
```

The commentId is reused so that it should be the same in both collections, so I can reuse this in my rules. The previous example obviously fails, because to insert in one location, I require that it is already inserted in the other location and vice versa.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the minimum code with which you can get the rules to reject?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to set these Security Rules to "make sure that these two comments are **always both created**". Since you are using a Batched Write you don' t need to use a Security Rules to ensure that "two comments are always both created" because, "by nature", **batched writes are atomic**.

Comment: @user2696806 Thanks for the clarifications: your goal is more clear now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

A cloud function would be much more suited to solve this problem. With an onCreate trigger, this document could be automatically created /users after creation under /threads. That being said, my old solution, without cloud functions, is below:

**Solution without cloud functions:**

There is no existsAfter() equivalent of getAfter() (the function that exists to validate data after a batch or transaction). So how I did it is with the following rules:

```
  match /users/{userId}/comments/{commentId} {  
    allow create: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/threads/$(request.resource.data.threadId)/comments/$(commentId)).data.author == userId;
  }

  match /threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId} {  
    allow create: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/comments/$(commentId)).data.createdAt == request.time;
  }
```

The getAfter() functions will check the validity after the back write and will get check the value of the field. Since I only need to check if they exist, the value of the field does not really matter.

Comment: Has the `existsAfter` method been added since the answer was posted? Looks like it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.existsAfter